# How to convert columns to number quickly without know the NA value patterns

Tags: csv, pandas

I have many CSV files with the same column titles to parse. In these files, there maybe several patterns to represent NA, for example: "-", "--", "/", ...

I don't know all the patterns, so I can't set `na_values` argument for `read_csv()` correctly.

Are there any quick way to find all NA patterns in those files, or without know all the patterns, I can still convert all the columns to number? Here is what I tried:

```
patterns = set()
for i, fn in enumerate(glob(u"data/*.csv")):
    df = pd.read_csv(fn, encoding="utf-8-sig", usecols=cols, dtype=str, keep_default_na=False)
    df_num = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
    patterns.update( df[df_num.isnull()].stack().value_counts().index )
```

But `convert_objects()` is slow. Here is some test:

- `read_csv(dtype=str)`: about 2.2s
- `read_csv()` without `dtype` argument: about 2.5s
- `read_csv(dtype=str)` + `convert_objects()`: 8.4s

So, `read_csv()` can convert strings to numbers very quickly than `convert_objects()`. But if there is one element that can't be converted to number, the whole column will become a string column.

Are there any faster method that can convert all columns to number without set `na_values` argument?

Comment: Could you not just pass all known possible values for `NaN` to `na_values`? Otherwise I think you're stuck with your current methods

Comment: Is numpy's .astype(float) any faster?

Answer (score 1):

If you have pandas version >= `0.17.0` you could try to apply [`pandas.to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) for each column (or may be you know suspicious columns):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 'b', 'a', 6], 'b':[0, 1, 2, 'a', 3, 4, 'b']}, dtype=str)
```

Some benchmarking:

```
In [78]: %timeit df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 480 µs per loop

In [79]: %timeit df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
1000 loops, best of 3: 880 µs per loop
```

We could see that it's slower then convert_object. Let's pass `raw=True` for [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
In [82]: %timeit df.apply(pd.to_numeric, raw=True, errors='coerce')
1000 loops, best of 3: 288 µs per loop
```

And now it's getting almost 2 times faster then `convert_objects`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the 'index_col' argument to False. This will cause pandas to just number your columns sequentially starting from zero I believe. Here's what your code would look like with the change:

```
patterns = set()
for i, fn in enumerate(glob(u"data/*.csv")):
    df = pd.read_csv(fn, encoding="utf-8-sig", index_col=False, usecols=cols, dtype=str, keep_default_na=False)
    df_num = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
    patterns.update( df[df_num.isnull()].stack().value_counts().index )
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but when using index_col=False you may not need usecols=cols anymore.